# Stochastic matrix with structure

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

Let $P \in [0,1]^{(n \times n)}$ be a stochastic matrix i.e $P_{ij} > 0 ~ \forall i,j$ and $\sum_{j}P_{ij} = 1~ \forall i$. Now let us impose additional structure on $P$ by saying that $P_{ij} + P_{ji} = \frac{1}{n} ~\forall i \neq j$ (*). Do these matrices have a special name in literature? Are their properties well studied? Any references would be appreciated. Thanks!

(*) - Edited

Comment: Perhaps you meant $P_{ij}+P_{ji}=1$ for all $i\color{red}{\ne}j$? Otherwise $P$ does not exist when $n\ne2$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, thanks! I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be as described. Then

$$\sum_i \sum_j P_{ij} = \sum_i 1 = n,$$

but

\begin{align*}
\sum_j \sum_i P_{ij} &= \sum_j \left( P_{jj} + \sum_{i,\ i \ne j} (1 - P_{ji})  \right) = \sum_j \left( P_{jj} - (1 - P_{jj}) + \sum_i (1 - P_{ji}) \right) \\
&= \sum_j \left( 2P_{jj} - 1 + \sum_i (1 - P_{ji}) \right) = \sum_j \left( 2P_{jj} - 1 + n - \sum_i P_{ji} \right) \\
&= \sum_j \left( 2P_{jj} - 1 + n - 1 \right) = 2 \sum_j P_{jj} - 2n + n^2.
\end{align*}

Both of these sums represent sum of all the elements in the matrix, so

$$n = 2 \sum_j P_{jj} - 2n + n^2,$$

i.e.,

$$n^2 - 3n + 2 \sum_j P_{jj} = 0.$$

Denoting $s := \sum_j P_{jj}$, we see that

$$n = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{9 - 8s}}{2} \le 3. \tag{*}$$

So, your matrices must be of order:

- $n = 1$: the only is $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$;
- $n = 2$: all have the form $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1-x & x \\ 1-x & x \end{bmatrix}, \ x \in [0,1]$; or
- $n = 3$: all have the form $P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & x & 1-x \\ 1-x & 0 & x \\ x & 1-x & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \ x \in [0,1]$.

  The diagonal zeroes come from $(*)$. As [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) wrote in the comments, such $P$ is the transition matrix of a biased random walk on the cycle $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

I expect there is no name for them, nor they are much researched, since there is not really that many of them.

Comment: When n=3 the (3,3) coefficient is y+z-1 instead of 1-(y+z). Once this correction is made, one can study the signs of the entries of P. This leads first to the conclusion that the diagonal of P is zero, then to the fact that every solution is P=[[0|x|1-x][1-x|0|x][x|1-x|0]] (that is, the transition matrix of a biased random walk on the cycle Z/3Z).

Comment: @Did Thank you for the correction. The diagonal zeroes actually follow from the formula for $n$, after which the rest of the elements are found trivially.

Comment: Excellent. You might also want to add to your post the interpretation of the 3x3 matrices I gave in my comment.

Comment: @Did I am not familiar with random walks and their matrices. I've managed to Google them, of course, but can you suggest one link to include, so that the addition to the answer is properly educational? Thanks!

Comment: My opinion is that no link is needed here for the addition to be "properly educational", but hey... this is your answer. (Likewise, the n=2 case has a nice probabilistic interpretation, which you might want to add...with no link needed.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I missed an important condition that i had in mind. The condition i was looking for is $P_{ij} + P_{ji} = \frac{1}{n}$. Now such matrices can be defined for any $n$ and looked as a Markov chains, they are aperiodic. I will edit the question appropriately.